# Can birt report call another birt report?

Tags: hyperlink, report, birt

I have one report (Mainreport. Rptdesign) that forms a hyperlink to one of several reports (depending on the parameters) (Res1. Rptdesign, Res2. rptdesign... etc.). Each time mainreport. rptdesign can generate only one hyperlink. How do I do so that the user did not have to click on the link and subreport runed on their own?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answered, I will write the decision which I have found. 
Yes it is possible.
Place a "text item" on the form. Define its content type as HTML and write this script

```js
<script> 
var targetURL = new String(location.href);
var ToURL = new String;
ToURL = 'New_report_which_I_call.rptdesign&__format=pdf&__';
ToURL += params["where"].value;
targetURL = targetURL.replace('Report_from_which_I_call.rptdesign', ToURL); 
window.open(targetURL);
</script>
```

Now you can make logic and call different reports from the same report.